# Mysql 8 crashing and showing the following message "mysqld got signal 11"

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me with the following Mysql error?

I am using the following version: mysql  Ver 8.0.18 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

This error is happening only on production server. I have tried local and on different envs and everything looks ok. Thank you in advance

```
13:02:37 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7fa57db99c00
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fa583625d50 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x55764ef2ac9d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x303) [0x55764e03cba3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7fa59ede1890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x18eb38) [0x7fa59d2bcb38]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(temptable::Row::copy_to_own_memory(std::vector<temptable::Column, temptable::Allocator<temptable::Column> > const&, unsigned long) const+0x456) [0x55764f4b70a6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(temptable::Table::insert(unsigned char const*)+0xcf) [0x55764f4ba7ef]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_write_row(unsigned char*)+0x194) [0x55764e155bc4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Table_function::write_row()+0x1b) [0x55764e36b79b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Table_function_json::fill_json_table()+0x308) [0x55764e36dee8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Table_function_json::fill_result_table()+0xe4) [0x55764e36e004]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(MaterializedTableFunctionIterator::Init()+0x23) [0x55764e0fa233]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(NestedLoopIterator::Read()+0xa1) [0x55764e0fa411]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(JOIN::exec()+0x722) [0x55764ded6b02]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute_inner(THD*)+0x2ee) [0x55764df5d23e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x458) [0x55764df64788]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x1e9f) [0x55764df1135f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Prepared_statement::execute(String*, bool)+0x834) [0x55764df41574]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Prepared_statement::execute_loop(String*, bool)+0xae) [0x55764df43d8e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysqld_stmt_execute(THD*, Prepared_statement*, bool, unsigned long, PS_PARAM*)+0x1d1) [0x55764df45481]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x2891) [0x55764df16bb1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x1a1) [0x55764df17b61]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0xf27010) [0x55764e02e010]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2329e79) [0x55764f430e79]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76db) [0x7fa59edd66db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x3f) [0x7fa59d24f88f]
```

Comment: `Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware` - Reinstall MySql with different version and check if your hardware is good

Comment: This question is for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), this is about server administration/maintenance, not directly about programming

Comment: The MySQL community/mailing list/bug tracker might be more interested to see it- can you repro it reliably? Always in the same way? The stack trace indicates a memory copy op is in progress; are you certain there is no fault with the ram/memory management of your prod server?

Answer (score 1):

I handled by adding command in docker-compose.yml:

```
command: mysqld --innodb_force_recovery=6 --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

I also had this problem when my mac mini was power down

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating mysql version to 8.0.19

Answer (score 0):

This error means that Database Data is corrupted. You can try to start mysql instance in recovery mode and you will be able to do backup if you are lucky.
Depends on selected mode tables could be read only

> WARNING: Backup data files before starting service in recovery mode

To start mysql in recovery mode add `--innodb_force_recovery=<mode>` in your mysql startup parameter

**Example of docker-compose file:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysqrvice-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    volumes:
      - ~/volumes/MyProject/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=MyProject
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command: mysqld --innodb_force_recovery=6 --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

mysql supporting values from `0` to `6`
[Mysql recovery docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

If mysql started successfully you can use `mysqldump` or any other tools to do dump which you can restore on new mysql instance